# Opting out of auto layout for a single view?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view that performs layout of its subviews in code.  The layout is too complex for auto layout, and auto layout breaks the layout code.  Is there any way to force auto layout to leave this view's subviews alone?  I've tried overriding layoutSubviews, but no joy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-layout is enabled or disabled per storyboard or XIB. If your view is in its own XIB, then you can disable auto-layout for that XIB. If there are other views in your XIB that rely on auto-layout, you'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: Putting it in its own NIB appears to be the only solution.

Comment: Yeah it sucks you can't turn it on or off per scene.

Comment: You *can* position subviews manually (i.e. set their frames) for a given view as long as you do it *after* the auto layout engine is done with them (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in the WWDC videos.  layoutSubviews does not work the same under auto layout as it did before.  It does not stop auto layout from happening, but rather is an opportunity to add/change/remove constraints during layout.

Last night I tried moving the custom view to a different NIB and that seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

[You can mix auto layout and manual layout!](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-auto-layout/)

As long as ***none*** of a view's subviews are involved in ***any*** auto layout constraints that would trigger another auto layout pass on that view, you can override `layoutSubviews` and set the frame on each subview manually:

```
class MyView : UIView {

    //
    // mySubview is not involved in any constraints 
    // that would trigger another layout pass.
    // e.g., no explicit constraints set in IB.
    // 
    @IBOutlet weak var mySubview: UIView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()  // let auto layout engine run first

       //
       // Auto layout engine now done with this view so we can
       // set the frames how ever we wish since we have the last
       // word! 
       //
       mySubview.frame  = CGRectMake(...)
       ...

    }

}
```

The reason this works is that after `super.layoutSubviews()` is called, changing the frames on any subviews does *not* trigger another layout pass (all constraints related to subviews are satisfied and the auto layout engine is done with them);
therefore this method gets the last word on the position of its subviews!

- Note that `MyView` instances *can* have related auto layout constraints set and everything works fine.
- IB issues *no* warnings as long as you do *not* set any constraints on the subviews.

Comment: On macOS, the method to subclass would be `layout`.