# iOS 6 - Exempt a ViewController from Autolayout

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autolayout

In Storyboard you can now enable AutoLayout and it is a nice feature, but I wish to have one ViewController without it for the moment.

Is this possible? Or is it a whole project or nothing function only??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opting out of auto layout for a single view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788769/opting-out-of-auto-layout-for-a-single-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Edited for correctness
```

You can switch it off on a storyboard-by-storyboard basis or use a separate xib.

To turn it off on a storyboard:

1. Select a view-controller in your Storyboard
2. Select the "File Inspector" in the Utilities view (right-hand panel)
3. Scroll down and un-tick "Use Autolayout"

You can then use a different storyboard for those view controllers you want to not use Auto-Layout.  Not ideal, of course, but possible.

Comment: Sorry just realised you posted an answer:-) That option you gave is for the whole project. I have tried that.

Comment: SO essentially I would need to use 2 storyboards and somehow link them together?? Yeah i can see how it is not ideal:-) I will look into it more.

Comment: Essentially you instantiate the view controller from the separate Storyboard and present the view controller manually (no seque possible between two storyboards currently).

Comment: WRONG! This disable it for whole storyboard !

Comment: @EmilMarashliev: That's correct as per my answer (from 2012!); You can switch Autolayout on or off on a storyboard-by-storyboard basis. As in my answer.