# UISearchBar animation problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to make a `UISearchBar` expand when it becomes active.

The problem I'm having is that the search bar only expands after the user has typed at least 2 characters of text in there. Until then it is fixed in place. I added a `searchBar.alpha =0.7;` in there and that works, so this method seems to be being called as soon as a user touches the search bar

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch : (UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,10,250,self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
        // self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(70, 10, 250, 40);
        searchBar.alpha =0.7;
        [searchBar layoutSubviews];            
    }];    
}
```

Not sure if the way I've set it up is the problem. Here's what I have:

in the `.h`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

in the `.m`:

```
@synthesize searchBar;
```

and in the `StoryBoard`:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue with animating a UISearchBar size and position and it turned out that the issue was related to autolayout in iOS 6. The animation block in my code is exactly like yours except that I call it from - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar.

I found through Logs that `searchBar.frame` was getting overriden at `layoutSubviews` in my Search Bar subclass. This Q&A explains how 'layoutSubviews' behaves differently on iOS 6 ([Opting out of auto layout for a single view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788769/opting-out-of-auto-layout-for-a-single-view))

Based on that, if you are building for iOS 6, the options to animate the UISearchBar frame seem to be either to disable autolayout or instantiate a UISearchBar programmatically. I opted for the latter and it worked.

P.S.: If you go for disabling autolayout, you can either disable it for the entire storyboard or only a .xib (More on this here: [Enabling auto layout in iOS 6 while remaining backwards compatible with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the class delegate of UISearchBar (`UISearchBarDelegate`) and paste your animation code in `- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` method implementation. I think it should help.

Comment: thanks! that animates and expand the searchBar. the keyboard now doesn't show though...

Comment: You should `return YES;` after animation code in that method and it'll show the keyboard.